# Rearrangment of convergent series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider the convergent series $$1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{6}+\cdots \tag{$*$}$$ and one of its rearrangments $$1+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{11}-\frac{1}{6}+\cdots \tag{$**$}$$ in which two positive terms are always followed by one negative.

How to prove that the series $(**)$ is convergent? I do not need his sum. I only want to prove that it's converges.

Let $S'_n$ is $n$th partial sum of $(**)$. Then I prove that $S'_{3n}=H_{4n}-\frac{1}{2}H_n-\frac{1}{2}H_{2n}$.

Can anyone show how to prove the convergence?

Comment: What's the logic behind the rearrangement, regardless of sign?

Comment: I did not understand you. We have the convergent series $(*)$ and after rearrangment we got the series $(**)$. How to prove that $(**)$ also converges?

Comment: Just in case you don't know it, look up Riemann series theorem.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test

Answer (score 2):

The sum of the two consecutive positive terms is always smaller in absolute value than is the foregoing negative term, and is always larger in absolute value than is the following negative term.  That means in effect you get alternation between positive and negative terms with absolute values always decreasing, and the terms approach $0$.  Then apply the usual criterion about "alternating series".
$$
1+\frac{1}{3}-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{11}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)+\cdots
$$

Comment: Is the implication here that all possible rearrangements have a certain property?

Comment: @mistermarko : Certainly not.  It is only that this particular arrangement has a certain property. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Michael your claim in your answer is wrong - It should be: "The sum of the two consecutive positive terms is always LARGER in absolute value than is the foregoing negative term. So the rest is not accurate. The other answer is correct.

Comment: Dear Michael Hardy! You are groping some terms. Yes? Is it legal? Can you explain this moment?

Comment: Bounded grouping is OK if the terms  go to $0$.

Comment: We got that the series $(1+1/3)-1/2+(1/5+1/7)-1/4+(1/9+1/11)-1/6+\dots$ converges. What about series $(**)$?

Comment: @Moti : I stand by my statement.  $\dfrac 1 5 + \dfrac 1 7$ is indeed SMALLER than $\dfrac 1 2$.  And $\dfrac 1 9 + \dfrac 1 {11}$ is SMALLER than $\dfrac 1 4$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Pacman: Look at it this way.  One of the partial sums is $\cdots+\dfrac{-1}4$.  Two steps later you have $\cdots+\dfrac{-1}4 + \left(\dfrac 1 9 + \dfrac 1 {11}\right)$. If we include partial sums that end after a negative term or end after a group of positive terms, then I've shown the sequence of partial sums that we include converges.  But what happens if we include the other partial sums, the one ending in $\dfrac 1 9$?  That other partial sum is BETWEEN the two we looked at first.  If the terms of a sequence are BETWEEN the terms of two sequences that both${}\,\ldots\qquad{}$

Comment: $\ldots\,{}$converge to the SAME limit, then we can draw a conclusion from that.  This is an instance of _squeezing_. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Michael The logic is to compare 1/2 to (1+1/3), and 1/4 to (1/5+1/7), as Pacman did! I think that your response was not leading to a useful result when compared with the GREAT! response by Keith, that did not need any editing!

Comment: @Moti : You seem to have misunderstood the word "foregoing".  When I wrote "foregoing", I meant "foregoing".  The word "foregoing" tells you WHICH negative terms I was comparing to each pair of positive terms. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: You are talking English and I am talking math. No sense in making a complicated suggestion while there is a straight forward simple solution. That all, your suggestion is not really helpful... at least in my opinion when compared to Keith solution. I do not understand why you get a reward of 1 and Keith not. I think Keith solution is the one that should be accepted.

Comment: @Moti : And yet what I did solves the problem. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: You did not solve mathematically. You claim the term "decreasing" (why?) this is not proving that the series converging - at least as I understand it. Keith proof is ELEGANT and demonstrate a best practice to approach solutions to such challenges.

Comment: @Moti : Indeed, I did not fully explain why the terms must be decreasing in absolute value, but that should be easy to figure out, and if anyone wants to know, I can explain it. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

If you add up each triad, you can show that each is positive and of order $1\over{n^2}$. You can then use the terms of the series $1\over{n^2}$ to show that there is an upper bound and you have strictly increasing terms. Hence there is a limit.

As a hint, write each triad as:

$$A_n = {1\over{4n-3}} +{1\over{4n-1}} - {1\over{2n}}$$

Comment: I proved that: $S'_3<S'_6<S'_9<...$. But I don't know how to prove  that there is an upper bound.

Comment: @pacman the suggestion, if I've understood it correctly, is to bound each $S_{3k}$ by a constant times $\frac{1}{n^2}$ and use the comparison test.

Comment: @Callus. Exactly - thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Excellent response (you were just faster than me), leaving some reasonable work to Pacman. Pacman, I think you should reward Keith by accepting his answer.